# JSHint error "Object doesn't support this property or method" for javascript closures

Tags: javascript, jslint, wsh, jshint

I have this javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    // a comment
})(window.jQuery);
```

I'm running the [wsh version](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/env/wsh.js) of [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) with these options:

Command:

```
%systemroot%\system32\cscript.exe
```

Arguments:

```
//Nologo "%userprofile%\Documents\jshint\env\wsh.js" /forin:true,noarg:true,noempty:true,eqeqeq:true,bitwise:true,undef:true,unused:true,browser:true,jquery:true,indent:4,maxerr:500 $(ItemPath)
```

(The `$(ItemPath)` is replaced by the current selected item in Visual Studio)

...And it's giving me this output:

```
[%pathname%\js\JScript1.js]
Line 3 character 18: Object doesn't support this property or method

Implied globals:
    window: 3
```

I've tried arranging the parens to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) style, but that gives me the same error:

```
(function ($) {
    // a comment
}(window.jQuery));
```

Am I doing something wrong with my javascript or is this a JSHint bug?

**Update:** I'm leaning towards JSHint bug, this javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    // a comment
})(window.jQuery);
// is this a bug?
window.alert("maybe?");
```

Gives me this error:

```
Line 5 character 23: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

**Update #2:** I think that this is the correct way to pass in args to `wsh.js`:

```
//U //Nologo "%userprofile%\Documents\jshint\env\wsh.js" /forin:true /noarg:true /noempty:true /eqeqeq:true /bitwise:true /undef:true /unused:true /browser:true /jquery:true /indent:4 /maxerr:500 $(ItemPath)
```

However, this code:

```
(function (w, $) {})(window, jQuery);
```

Still outputs this:

```
[%pathname%\js\JScript1.js]
Line 1 character 37: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

**Update #3:** It turns out, I am indeed an idiot.

I was trying to use the latest: 
https://nodeload.github.com/jshint/jshint/zipball/master

...When I should have been using **r09**: 
https://nodeload.github.com/jshint/jshint/zipball/r09

Comment: are you sure the error isn't in wsh.js itself?  is there anything suspicious at line 3 char 18 in wsh.js?

Comment: @Dan Davies Brackett it might be, but the line # and character # always changes to the last character in my source js.

Comment: JSHint maintainer here.

Could you please create a ticket? Master shouldn't fail like this.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, submitted: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a bug in latest master and it's been fixed for the r10 release: http://www.jshint.com/changelog/

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to pass `window.jQuery` as a parameter through the self-instantiating anonymous function, but rather `window, jQuery`. The Object `window` does not have the method `jQuery`, hence the error.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case, I'm passing in `browser:true,jquery:true` as arguments when calling wsh.js. Also, this code has the same error: `(function ($) {})("hi");` Plus, when using `window.jQuery` the `.jQuery` would just be an `undefined` property of the `window` object.